# How to calculate the complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms

How to calculate: $\int_{1}^{i}{\log(z)}\,dz$? I am beginner on this topic.

Comment: Does $(z \ln z - z)' = \ln z$ help?

Comment: But $logz$ is a complex logarithm..

Comment: From $1$ to $i$ following a straight line?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the integration is done along the segment joining $1$ and $i$ whose parametric equation is $\gamma(t)=t+i (1-t),\;0\le t\le 1$. So we have [(look here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral)

$$\int_{\gamma} \log z \, dz=\int_0^1 (1-i) \log (t+i (1-t)) \, dt=\frac{\pi }{2}-1+i$$